Compilation fails with XeLaTeX compiler of a tex file that has Lohit Devanagari font requirement
I am trying to compile a tex file that uses Lohit Devanagari font. I am compiling with XeLaTeX compiler on PyCharm with TeXiFy-idea plugin on Macbook.
The part of the tex file that is causing the error is the following
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{sanskrit}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Lohit Devanagari}

\begin{document}
\begin{sanskrit}
    कर्मण्येवाधिकारस्ते मा फलेशु कदाचन।
\end{sanskrit}
\end{document}

I am getting the following error
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecmds/makecmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-latex.lde))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-english.ldf)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-sanskrit.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/devanagaridigits.sty)
))

/Users/nagabhushan/Data/Studies/07_IISc/Research/Thesis/snb_thesis/main.tex:4: 
Package fontspec Error: The font "Lohit Devanagari" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.4 \input{chapters/others/UsePackages}
                                       
? 


Please tell us the full path to the file Lohit-Devanagari.ttf. This piece of information may be found toward the end of the log file. E.g., on my MacBook Air with MacOS 15.1 "Sequoia", the path is /Users/mico/Library/Fonts/.

Installing Lohit fonts using Homebrew worked.
brew install fonts-encodings
brew install --cask font-lohit

